# EMR Hue: CUSTOM server authentication not supported. Valid are ['NONE', 'KERBEROS', 'PAM', 'NOSASL', 'LDAP']

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, emr, hue

When I enable "CUSTOM" authentication for Hive, Hue is unable to make a connection to HiveServer2. It throws the following error:

```
CUSTOM server authentication not supported. Valid are ['NONE', 'KERBEROS', 'PAM', 'NOSASL', 'LDAP'].
```

Does that mean Hue doesn't work if we configure Hive with custom authentication provider? Hive itself is working fine, also JDBC/ODBC working as expected using custom authentication.

Is there any workaround for this?

Ref: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-6128 (more explanation on https://github.com/cloudera/hue/issues/480)